# Move from one html page to the next through javascript and keyevent

Tags: javascript, html

By only using JS/HTML, I want to detect if the space bar is hit, and when it's hit, I want to change the html to another file. (Note, im just working off localhost, so I want to go from localhost:1337 to localhost:1337/mainmenu)

This is what I have, but there seems to be an underlying issue. I have a index.html file and a index.js file. I have a script in my js file that allows text to fade in and out. That script runs fine. However when I added in the script for my keyboard event, the first script seems to stop working.

Can someone point out if the two scripts are interfering with each other? Also, can someone explain why my keyboard script wont run?

JS:

```
var speed = 1000; 
var t = setInterval(function(){
  var slideSource = document.getElementById('play');
  slideSource.classList.toggle('fade');
}, speed);

//SEPERATE SCRIPTS
window.addEventListener("keydown", pressToPlay, false);
function checkSpacebar(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == "32") {
        window.location.href = "localhost:1337/mainmenu";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <div class="container">
    <img src="images/image.jpg" alt="Loading Image.." style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <div class="title">
    <img src = "images/redfox.png" style = "width:7%">
    Oregon Trail:Marist Edition 
    <div class = "marist"><img src = "images/marist.png" style = "width:15%"></div>
    <img src = "images/redfox.png" style = "width:7%"></div>
    <div id ="play">Press Spacebar To Play!</div>
    </div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/index.css">
    <script src="/JS/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: resolved the issue, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
//SEPERATE SCRIPTS
    window.addEventListener("keydown", checkSpaceBar, false);
    function checkSpaceBar(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == "32") {
            window.location.href = "localhost:1337/mainmenu";
        }
    }
```

ES6 style minified

```
window.addEventListener("keydown",(e) => {if(e.keyCode === 32) window.location.href="localhost:1337/mainmenu";}, false);
```

Comment: So, I added this, and my first script now continues to work, but my webpage does not change, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes in your `JavaScript` code, you're passing an undefined variable(in fact a callback function) to the keydown event listener, and you began a string with `"` and close it with `'` and that generates an Unexpected Token error, thus your code will crash, so you should either use `"` or `'` not the two at the same time.

Here's your code with the required modifications:

```
// your passing an undefined pressToPlay function instead of checkSpacebar
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkSpacebar, false);

function checkSpacebar(e) {
    // use "32" or '32' and as of the keyCode attribute is an integer then no need to use 32 as a string, I mean instead of "32" write just 32.
    if(e.keyCode == 32) {
        window.location.href = "localhost:1337/mainmenu";
    }
}
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Answer (score 0):

Add Http before URL.

```
    window.addEventListener("keydown", checkSpaceBar, false);
        function checkSpaceBar(e) {
            if(e.keyCode == "32") {
               window.open('http://localhost:1337/mainmenu',"_self");
            }
        }
```